# How long until the rights of Marvel characters that 20th Century Fox own revert to Marvel Studios?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe

The Marvel Cinematic Universe is currently unable to use various characters or the term 'mutants' thanks to the fact that 20th Century Fox own the live action rights to the X-Men and their related characters.

Is the deal that allowed 20th Century Fox to use Marvel characters permanent? If not, when can we expect to see mutants in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

When Marvel sold the live action rights to many of their characters and groups of characters in the 1990's, it was on the condition that the rights would revert back to Marvel if the properties were not used within a certain number of years.

This condition has led to the rights for various characters reverting to Marvel since, the latest and most well-known being the rights to the character of Daredevil after 20th Century Fox failed to do anything with the rights since the 2005 *Elektra* movie, which has resulted in Marvel Studios successfully creating the Netflix exclusive *Daredevil* series as part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

As such, we can conclude that X amount of years will have to pass without 20th Century Fox creating an X-Men-related property before mutants can appear in the Marvel Cinematic Universe. Unfortunately, as far as I am aware no one who is not privy to the details of the rights and licensing contract between 20th Century Fox and Marvel Studios knows the exact timeframe required to pass before the rights naturally revert.

**If the deal for X-Men was the same as the deal for Daredevil (whose rights reverted towards the end of 2012, 7 years after they were last used by 20th Century Fox in *Elektra*) then we can say, at least for now, that the rights will probably not revert until ~7 years after 20th Century Fox stop using them, which at the time of writing means 2023 at the earliest, 7 years after the release of the 2016 *X-Men: Apocalypse* film.** However, we can be fairly certain that more X-Men films will be made after that, with a third Wolverine film already in the works.

However, a recent deal between Marvel Studios and Sony Pictures (who own the live action rights to Spider-Man) has resulted in Spider-Man becoming a part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe in the upcoming *Captain America: Civil War*. Although the rights to the character still belong to Sony Pictures, the deal means that each studio can use characters and events from the others films in order to bolster their own films, so we can expect to see Spider-Man appear in future Marvel Cinematic Universe films, and the upcoming Spider-Man films to reference events from the Marvel Cinematic Universe and potentially use character from other films.

Despite this deal giving many people hope that we will soon see mutants in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, the fact that the X-Men movies have been more successful for 20th Century Fox than the recent Spider-Man movies have been for Sony Pictures means that the studio is under no financial pressure to make a deal. As such, as far as we as the general public are aware, there are no plans (despite it being possible) to introduce mutants into the Marvel Cinematic Universe, which has resulted in Marvel Studios attempting to use their Inhumans property as a mutant substitute for now.

It is also worth mentioning that the inclusion of Quicksilver and the Scarlet Witch in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* is not indicative of a 20th Century Fox/ Marvel Studios deal - these characters were mutants first and Avengers second, meaning that both studios own the rights to the character and can use them as they see fit as long as Marvel Studios don't reference mutants and 20th Century Fox don't mention The Avengers. This has led to the potentially confusing situation where two different versions of the same character have appeared in two unrelated films (Quicksilver in both *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and *X-Men: Days of Future Past*).

Comment: Sorry for the essay, but it's a complex topic.

Comment: **we can say, at least for now, that the rights will probably not revert until ~7 years after 20th Century Fox stop using them, which at the time of righting means 2023**

Comment: @Daft Good call, bolded that sentence in the answer.

Comment: Wolverine 3 had a release date of 3rd March 2017 announced. I’m not sure that the X-Men films have been more successful than the Spider-Man films, at least financially. *The Amazing Spider-Man 2* took $709M at the box office on a $200M budget, similar to *X-Men: Days of Future Past*’s $746M on the same budget. *First Class* in 2011 took $353M, compared to *The Amazing Spider-Man*’s $752M in 2012.

Comment: “each studio can use characters and events from the others films in order to bolster their own films” — is that right? My understand was that Spider-Man will appear in *Captain America: Civil War* next year, and Sony and Marvel will jointly produce a *Spider-Man* film for summer 2017, but I didn’t think Sony was planning to produce any superhero films on its own.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I'm not just talking financial success - the X-Men films have been much more critically successful than the more recent Spider-Man films. The new Spider-Man film will be produced, distributed and financed by Sony Pictures, with Kevein Feige is co-producing it - it's is not officially a partnership between the two studios as such. Unofficially, I imagine Feige will pretty much be running things.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite "Wolverine 3 had a release date of 3rd March 2017 announced." Drew Goddard's *Sinister Six* also had a release date in 2016 annoumced, but that was canned after *The Amazing Spider-Man 2* inflicted itself upon the world. Until a film actually begins production I'd rather not count it.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: why would Sony care particularly about the critical reception? I think it’s more the fact that *The Amazing Spider-Man 2* didn’t do *better* than the first film, and thus probably couldn’t sustain a multi-character franchise like Marvel can, that made them scrap their future plans (i.e. the Sinister Six and Venom movies). I see your point re Wolverine, I just thought I’d add the detail.

Comment: Fox made a Fantastic Four movie in 1994, with a very small budget, just to prevent those movie rights from reverting to Marvel. It was never even intended to be released. So, the movie rights will not revert to Marvel for a loooong time. Not until Fox will start to lose money on them. They are not so friendly with Marvel as Sony is, so some kind of deal is also unlikely to happen.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite "Why would Sony care particularly about the critical reception?" Because poor reception from critics and audience means that people are less likely to go see a sequel. We live in a world connected in a million ways that didn't exist 10 years ago, and word of mouth matters a lot more than it used to. Your point about the mutli-character franchise rings true.

Comment: @Dennis_E That film wasn't produced or distributed by Fox, from what I have read.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: eh, maybe. I really think studios pay a lot more attention to box office and audience reaction than critics. *Amazing 2* and *Thor* have equivalent Metacritic scores, for instance. I’m with you on the audience stuff.

Comment: @Dennis_E: [he’s got you there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fantastic_Four_%28unreleased_film%29#Production).

Comment: @DrRDizzle I guess I got some things mixed up. I'm not that familiar with movie studios and legal deals. Anyway, Fox has no intention of giving up the movie rights any time soon.

Comment: @Dennis_E: I don’t think that these days Fox would throw together a poor-quality Fantastic Four movie just to ensure the rights didn’t revert to Mar... ah, [then again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four_(2015_film)#Critical_response).

Comment: There's the possibility of ol' man Wolverine will appear in the future MCUs. [Read here.](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/An-X-Men-Avengers-Crossover-Here-What-Hugh-Jackman-Says-70110.html)

Comment: @Aogiri I'm afraid that Hugh Jackman saying he'd love a crossover to happen is a very different thing entirely to two rival companies deciding to work together in spite of the various character rights issues they'd first have to sort out. It's not literally impossible, but for all intents and purposes it may as well be at this point.

Comment: You could update that now to include _Logan_.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I could, but I don't intend to update this answer every time a new X-Men film comes out. I think the way it's worded now provides enough context as it is.

Comment: It's worth noting that, in at least [two](https://arstechnica.com/the-multiverse/2015/02/you-probably-missed-the-terrible-wheel-of-time-tv-series-pilot-on-monday/) separate [cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fantastic_Four_(unreleased_film)) something poor has been produced just so the rights would not revert. The resulting product is called an [Ashcan Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashcan_copy)

Comment: @Machavity Dang. I was hoping for a TVTropes link.

Answer (score 9):

#### 21st Century Fox's Marvel characters film rights are now owned by Marvel Studios.

In March 2019, Marvel Studios’ parent company, [Disney, acquired 21st Century Fox](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/general-news/disney-closes-fox-deal-creating-global-content-powerhouse-1174498/).

The term “mutant” has been used in the MCU, and several mutant characters have now appeared or have been announced to appear under the Marvel Studios banner:

- **Professor X** / **Charles Xavier** in *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), complete with [*X-Men: The Animated Series* opening theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=di6DocEkruk) hook playing while he was being introduced.
- **Ms. Marvel** / **Kamala Khan** in *Ms. Marvel* (2022 TV series), although not a mutant in the comics, she was referred to as having a “mutation” by Bruno Carrelli in *Ms. Marvel* S01E06 “No Normal”, again complete with the *X-Men: The Animated Series* opening theme hook playing while "mutation" was mentioned.
- **Namor** in *Black Panther: Wakanda Forever* (2022). In the film, Namor mentions that he is a mutant.
- **Mister Immortal** and **El Aguila**: these characters are mutants in the comics; they appeared in *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law* (2022 TV series).
- **Beast** / **Hank McCoy** has appeared in *The Marvels* (2023).
- **Wolverine** and other mutants will appear in *Deadpool 3* (2024), which will be set in the MCU.
- ***[X-Men '97](https://www.marvel.com/articles/tv-shows/this-week-in-marvel-exclusive-interview-x-men-97-animated-series-hits-disney-plus)***, the first X-Men title from Marvel Studios, is scheduled for a 2024 release on Disney+. The show will continue the story of the original *X-Men: The Animated Series*.

Non-mutant characters whose film rights were previously owned by Fox:

- **Deadpool** will appear in *Deadpool 3* (2024), an MCU film.
- **Reed Richards** / **Mister Fantastic** appeared in *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022).
- Marvel Studios president [Kevin Feige has announced that a *Fantastic Four* film set in the MCU is in development.](https://www.comingsoon.net/movies/news/1085183-comic-con-fantastic-four-confirmed-for-the-mcu#/slide/1)

Comment: That's one way of doing it. Don't buy the rights, but the company that holds the rights

Answer (score 3):

Disney-Marvel are in talks to buy Fox Movie Company and other Fox assets from Ruppert Murdoch's parent organization (2017). If this deal goes through, Disney-Marvel will automatically acquire all rights to Marvel characters through the acquisition of the Fox companies.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this? This seems pretty speculative.

Comment: According to Bloomberg, the negotiations are dead.

Comment: https://www.theverge.com/2017/12/14/16735502/disney-fox-deal-film-tv-studio-acquisition