# Could "Old Man Logan" be used in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, wolverine

With the 616 version of Wolverine

> still dead

Marvel comics is bringing the Old Man Logan version of the character into their new post-Secret Wars universe.

Since a lot of the things happening in the comics seems to be geared towards future movies, like female Thor and Falcon as Captain America, is it possible that this re-branding of Wolverine as Old Man Logan could be used as a loophole to steal Wolverine from FOX?

Could they use Old Man Logan in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Comment: Don't they already have MCU movies planned out for the next 100 years, anyway? Who knows what the legal situation will be like with Fox and rights to the X-Men by then.

Comment: Is this on-topic?

Comment: @Anthony Grist But they have already shown that they are willing to change their plans as soon as a major character(Spider-Man) becomes available to them.

Comment: @Daft I don't really consider it a spoiler. The comic was called "Death Of Wolverine".

Comment: @Boelabaal You didn't mention the title in the question. But I suppose it's beside the point, I don't think discussing film studio legal loopholes is on-topic.

Comment: @Boelabaal and obviously you can delete the spoiler tag if you want to. I'm just a stickler for spoilers.

Comment: @Daft There's precedent for it being on-topic. We've had questions about who owns the rights to various works or characters before, including Marvel and X-Men I think. I'm not sure they're always great questions, though, since 1. most of us aren't lawyers and 2. the specifics and wording of the agreements isn't known.

Comment: @Daft There has been other questions about the Marvel character rights thing. PS I wasn't trying to be snarky about the spoiler tag, just saying why I didn't use one.

Comment: @Daft From the site tour - "Ask about... Behind-the-scenes and fandom information". It's on topic.

Comment: @Boelabaal Is there anything you think my answer is missing? If not, I would appreciate it if you would accept it.

Comment: @Dr R Dizzle Sorry doctor, I've been distracted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR - Almost certainly not.**

20th Century Fox are the current owners of the live action rights to the character of Wolverine, and have been since the early 90's when Marvel sold the live action rights to many of their characters. Further details about the nature of these contracts (specifically the concept of the rights reverting to Marvel Studios after a set amount of years) can be found in [my answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/90394/24087).

The upcoming *Wolverine* film (spin off from the main X-Men films and semi-sequel to *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* and *The Wolverine*) sounds as if it may use elements from the Old Man Logan storyline according to Hugh Jackman himself.

> Speaking to a massive crowd in Hall H, Jackman said, “I’ve got three words for you guys: Old Man Logan.” The actor then added, “Take from that what you will.”

<sup>Quote courtesy of [this ScreenRant article](http://screenrant.com/wolverine-hugh-jackman-old-man-logan/)</sup>

As such, **Old Man Logan is almost certainly classed as a version Wolverine from a legal perspective**.

However, a recent deal between Marvel Studios and Sony Pictures (who own the live action rights to Spider-Man) has resulted in Spider-Man becoming a part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe in the upcoming *Captain America: Civil War*. Although the rights to the character still belong to Sony Pictures, the deal means that each studio can use characters and events from the others films in order to bolster their own films, so we can expect to see Spider-Man appear in future Marvel Cinematic Universe films, and the upcoming Spider-Man films to reference events from the Marvel Cinematic Universe and potentially use character from other films.

Despite this deal giving many people hope that we will soon see mutants in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, the fact that the X-Men movies have been more successful for 20th Century Fox than the recent Spider-Man movies have been for Sony Pictures means that the studio is under no financial pressure to make a deal. As such, as far as we as the general public are aware, there are no plans (despite it being possible) to introduce mutants into the Marvel Cinematic Universe, which has resulted in Marvel Studios attempting to use their Inhumans property as a mutant substitute for now.

It is also worth mentioning that the inclusion of Quicksilver and the Scarlet Witch in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* is not indicative of a 20th Century Fox/ Marvel Studios deal - these characters are mutants first and Avengers second, meaning that both studios own the rights to the character and can use them as they see fit as long as Marvel Studios don't reference mutants and 20th Century Fox don't mention The Avengers. This has led to the potentially confusing situation where two different versions of the same character have appeared in two unrelated films (Quicksilver in both *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and *X-Men: Days of Future Past*).

Comment: "these characters were Avengers first and mutants second," flip that around. they appeared in x-men #4 first and then went on to the avengers. that said, they have primarily been avengers characters since then, which is likely why the allowances were made.