# Why doesn't Tony Stark try to make a Vibranium Iron Man suit during Avengers: Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, vibranium

I've read [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43723/why-didnt-iron-man-make-a-vibranium-armor), but my question refers to the MCU **after** *Iron Man 2*, specifically during and post *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

After seeing all of the Vibranium kept by Ulysses Klaw in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, why did Tony never think to try and make a Vibranium Iron Man suit? In the same vein of thought, why hasn't he tried to make a suit of the more durable metals that he knows about such as Adamantium?

In short, I'm looking for canon reasons that Tony Stark hasn't at least mentioned/thought about/doodle-designed a "super-metal" suit yet.

Comment: The question you link to does cover the MCU. Focusing on adamantium specifically could bring it out of dupe territory (although it would be a short answer; I don't think adamantium is allowed to exist in the MCU), and I think specifically asking why Tony didn't take Klaw's vibranium to make a suit would also be okay

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate - the situation has changed since *Iron Man 2* (which the linked question deals with) after the discovery of large amounts of Vibranium in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, and as such this question is asking a different thing and needs a different answer.

Comment: Dr R Dizzle's comment is the exact reason I posted the question, in light of Age of Ultron where 1) Vast amounts of (the otherwise almost unknown) Vibranium were found. 2) An android was created of the material

The scope of the question has changed considerably since the linked question, they're definitely linked though.

Comment: I recommend reading the accepted (and highest rated) answer on the linked question, it actually states that the scope and answer to the question will change, as it has done. :p

Comment: @WadCheber What didn't I mention? As far as I can see I directly referenced the Vibranium cache (gathered by Klaw) and the android with a Vibranium body (The Vision)? Did I miss the point of your comment or..? :c

Comment: @Stormie You didn't say "After A2".  You just said "in the MCU".  The point is moot anyway.  I already voted to reopen it.

Comment: @WadCheber In the actual question text, it did say "as shown in AoU" a few times. I probably should've put it in the question title though, thanks

Comment: @Stormie I hope you don't mind the substantial edits I have made to the question - I've tried to get to the heart of your question, while cleaning it up.

Comment: @DrRDizzle No that's fine, you cut out all my waffle. Might edit it to add the "other metals" though, Adamantium may not be on the cards but there are other alien metals.. For instance the Chitauri armaments aren't earth metals, I assume. ;)

Comment: @Stormie I'd leave it as it if I were you - we don't even know the name of the Chitauri metals, never mind if they are stronger than the metal he already uses. You are in danger of making the question too broad.

Comment: I suppose you're right.. I guess I'll just post a similar question after Black Panther/GotG2/Inhumans. Whichever makes this relevant again. Thanks!

Comment: Umm...this seems like a dumb question. First off, Iron man 2 was not the last iron man film before age of ultron, 3 was. Second, that has no bearing on the question or answer. Third, ultron used all the vibranium while making vision. Fourth, adamantium is property of Fox, so its not part of the mcu.

Comment: @searchengine27: A better question would be: if Tony Stark knew where to find vibranium, why didn't he go get it in between Iron Man 3 and Avengers 2 to make a suit out of?

Comment: @Ellesedil he didn't know where it was. In Age of Ultron when Ultron left the Avengers tower and they didn't have internet, they only came to the realization that Ultron knew that Vibranium existed because he was going to contact Ulysses Klaue. Tony and Rogers both seemed thrown because both thought that all of the Vibranium was in Roger's shield. Also, one amendment to my previous comment, the bulk of the Vibranium was actually in the island that came down. I suspect that will come back in a later movie because they show it coming down in one solid piece in Age of Ultron, so it's intact still

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tony Stark didn't make suit of Vibranium during *Avengers: Age of Ultron* because he was the only one capable of stopping The Hulk when he started to rampage in Johannesburg, South Africa, which meant that he was forced away from the facility.

Although we don't see exactly what happens in Ulysses Klaue's facility while the Hulk vs Hulkbuster fight is going on, the fact that Ultron initially went there in order to get Vibranium could well mean that he took all of the Vibranium in the facility with him when he left - selfish, but the kind of thing a mass murdering meglomaniac machine might do if he doesn't want to allow his enemies to get any stronger.

As for your other question;

> "Why hasn't he tried to make a suit of the more durable metals that he knows about such as Adamantium?"

We know that Adamantium is a fictional, near indestructable metal in the Marvel Comics, and (in the comics) is actually used in the creation of Captain America's shield, which is made of a Vibranium-Adamantium alloy. However, in the films, we see the Captain America's shield is made of pure Vibranium, never once mentioning Adamantium.

This is due to the fact that Wolverine's skeleton is coated with Adamantium. After selling the live action rights to Wolverine (and the rest of the X-Men and several other Marvel characters) to 20th Century Fox in the early 90's, the film rights to the metal belong to 20th Century Fox and cannot be used by Marvel Studios. For more information on these contracts, you may want to read [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90388/how-long-until-the-rights-of-marvel-characters-that-20th-century-fox-own-revert?lq=1) and [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97024/could-old-man-logan-be-used-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe?lq=1)

Comment: I couldn't remember if they had said MCU Cap Shield was the alloy or not, thanks for clearing that up.

It just strikes me as odd that a "genius" like Tony Stark wouldn't think of doing something like this after being shown so much Vibranium **AND** seeing an android made of the stuff.. Maybe he really is unimaginative. ;p

Comment: @Stormie In fairness, if Ultron did clear Ulysses Klaw out of Vibranium, then Tony Stark still doesn't have access to any.

Comment: It's left ambiguous if he was cleaned out though, Ultron presents the Korean lady (I can't remember the name!) with only a single vial of Vibranium. I think I remember one of the Ultron-bots locking up the little room it was all kept in though.. Don't think they made off with it.

Either way, with Black Panther's movie coming out I'm sure we'll see more of it. His suit is made of two different types of Vibranium right?

Comment: @Stormie I think he used Vibranium in the creation of the thrusters that lifted Sokovia too, as well as his new body(?). I'm afraid I don't actually know all that much about the comics, so I don't know about Black Panthers suit. My knowledge is pretty much limited to the films and some basic stuff from the comics.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! It was to keep it together once it had lifted off. He probably was cleaned out.. You're right. I guess we'll have to wait for Black Panther and see what happens then. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Stormie: “It just strikes me as odd that a "genius" like Tony Stark wouldn't think of doing something like this after being shown so much Vibranium AND seeing an android made of the stuff” Bear in mind that a) we haven’t yet seen any MCU movies or TV shows featuring Tony Stark after Avengers 2, and b) Tony’s whole arc in Avengers 2 seemed to be about him not really wanting to be Iron Man any more. Ultron was his attempt to automate Iron Man’s job.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It was less about him not wanting to be Iron Man and more him beginning to worry that Iron Man wasn't enough. "A suit of armour around the world". Ultron was less an attempt at automating Iron Man as it was making Iron Man redundant.

Comment: I would also venture a guess saying it would be impossible to mass-produce the suits. Tony likes to have suits accessible at almost any location, so obviously has become very good at mass-producing them. Vibranium may just be too expensive to scale to this strategy.

Comment: The shield was made of an vibranium-iron alloy now known as proto-adamantium, from which adamantium was reverse-engineered.

Answer (score 1):

In Age Of Ultron, we find out that Tony is aware that there is more vibranium on earth and that he knows where to find it. When Bruce Banner informs the team that the marking on Klaue's neck is from Wakanda, Stark asks if klaue left Wakanda with some of it's "trade goods".

I think the reason why he hasn't made a vibranium suit yet is because he just can't get any. It's possible that Wakanda gives away little or none of its most precious resource, especially after the large amount that Klaue was able to steal. We later find out that Ultron uses all of it to build his last body and the huge spire used to lift Sokovia.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, starting with Mark 45 (one he used in Sokovia) his suits are actually made of vibranium (or have vibranium plating whatever you call it).

Comment: Do you have sources for this assertion?